# hightcharts mouse tracking color

Tags: javascript, css, charts, highcharts

I am using Highcharts to render a line chart (http://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-basic).

Every line in my chart has the same color and different markers on the end. Now what I want is when I hover over a line to change it's color.

Answer (score 2):

you can find mouse events in plotOptions there you can manipulate the colors

```
this.chart.series[index].update({color:'color'});
```

this piece of code will be helpful.

here is a working example http://jsfiddle.net/vytEE/

hope this will help you